# LDAP authentication for Lizmap - cannot authenticate to ldap

Tags: lizmap

I try to use the LDAP Server for the [lizmap authorisation](https://docs.lizmap.com/3.5/en/install/ldap.html).
I have the following configuration in the profiles.ini.php:

```
searchUserBaseDN="dc=XYZ,dc=ch"
searchUserFilter="(&(objectClass=*)(mail=%%LOGIN%%))"
searchAttributes="mail:login,givenName:firstname,sn:lastname,mail:email,dn:"
bindUserDN="$dn"

searchGroupFilter="(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=%%USERDN%%))"
searchGroupProperty="cn"
searchGroupBaseDN="ou=XYZ_WebGIS,dc=XYZ,dc=ch"
```

Unfortunately I always get this error:

```
ldapdao error: cannot authenticate to ldap with given bindUserDN for the login "xyz@gmail.com". Wrong DN or password
```

I use the following versions:

- ldapdao Modul-Version: 2.2.4
- Jelix-Version: 1.6.36-pre
- lizmap-web-client-3.5.1
- PHP Version: 7.4

Any idea what I did wrong?

BR,
Jürg